# Check if a directory exists as an absolute path

Tags: perl, unix, system

How would one check if the path/directory exists (-d) and is a full pathname from root directory?

```
i.e. ~/mysubdir vs /home/me/mysubdir vs mysubdir.
```

- I want the argument supplied to die if it is not a root path that
  exists. os specific for unix.
- Or, given a directory, get its full root path if it exists?

Comment: Just some terminology that might make searching easier: what you're calling a "root path" is usually called an absolute path, and a "non-root path" is called a relative path.

Comment: An absolute path is one which after tilde expansion begins with a slash. You can shortcut by looking for tilde or slash, and handle invalid tilde expansions separately later in the code.

Comment: @tripleee Careful about the tilde, not all programs interpret it as meaning $HOME. Try `perl -MFile::Find -e 'find(sub { print "$File::Find::name\n"; }, "~");'` --- it prints nothing, but clearly I do have files in `~`.

Comment: It seems rather clear from the question that the OP wants to support tilde expansion. If this is required in a context where it is not already supported, they'll have to implement it themselves, obviously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

use Cwd qw/abs_path getcwd/;
use File::HomeDir;

my $path = 'foo/../bar';

if($path =~ /^~/) {
    my $home = File::HomeDir->my_home;
    $path =~ s/^~/$home/;
}

if($path !~ m!^/!) {
    $path = getcwd . "/$path";
}

my $full_path = abs_path($path);

if(defined $full_path && -d $full_path) {
    say "$full_path exists";
} else {
    say "$path is non-existant";
}
```

`File::Homedir` will allow you to get a users home directory, and you
can then replace the tilde in the path.

If the path at this point doesn't start with `/` (is a relative path) prepend the current working directory with `getcwd`, to get an absolute path.

Once you've done that you can pass it through `abs_path` to resolve things like `.` and `..` as well as symlinks.

Finally you can then test that with `-d` to see if the resultant path exists.